# Run php file from another directory in php function

Tags: php, magento

User choose "**ACCEPTED**" from dropdown menu and click submit button, after that **test.php** of **these path** plus given below function must execute.
How i will able to do this?

**Path:**

```
/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php
```

**Here is the function:**

```
  if($testcodPayment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() == 'Cash On Delivery' && $status == $statusAccepted && ($checkTrack12[0]['number']=='') && $selectCourier == 'couriername'){

include '/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php' ;

            $awbNumbercouriername = $hlp->couriernameawbgenerate('couriername',$id);
            $title = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$method[0].'/title', $store);
                        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                            ->setNumber($awbNumbercouriername)
                            ->setCarrierCode($method[0])
                        ->setCourierName('couriername')
                            ->setTitle('couriername');
             $shipment->addTrack($track);
             Mage::helper('shipmenty')->addShipmentComment(
                        $shipment,
                        $this->__('%s addeddd tracking ID %s', $vendor->getVendorName(), $awbNumbercouriername)



                    );

        $session->addSuccess($this->__('Tracking ID has been added. Please take three printouts of each manifest and keep one copy of airway bill signed by courier boy with you as proof of pick up.  '));
        $highlight['tracking'] = true;
        $customerMessage = 'Your order has been shipped. Tracking Details.Shipment#: '.$_shipmentId.' , Track Number: '.$awbNumberFedex.'Courier Partner : www.fedex.com - Craftsvilla.com (Customercare email: customercare@craftsvilla.com)';
        $_customerSmsUrl = $_smsServerUrl."username=".$_smsUserName."&password=".$_smsPassowrd."&type=0&dlr=0&destination=".$customerTelephone."&source=".$_smsSource."&message=".urlencode($customerMessage);
        $parse_url = file($_customerSmsUrl);
        $shipment->save();



    }
```

Comment: Acually i tried, i gave include, require and file_get_contents function but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) command within your function and it should do the trick.

```
require('/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php');
```

Comment: what fatal error and what does your log file tell you about that error

Comment: Actually problem is with my test.php file, if i put demo hello world  code in my test.php file its execute but when i put my Real code in test.php it shows error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `include` or the `require` commands.

Suppose you want to execute `test.php` before your function.

Then, use

```
<?php

include '/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php';
yourFnction();

?>
```

You can also use `require`. The difference is that, if the file is not found, the script execution dies. Whereas, if you use `include`, even if the file is not found, the script will continue executing `yourFunction()`

```
<?php

include '/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php';
yourFunction();

?>
```

You can even call `include` inside the function

```
<?php

function yourFunction(){

echo "a";
include '/var/www/html/demo/courier/test.php';
echo "b";

}

?>
```

Comment: i want include() in function itself

Comment: You can call include anywhere you want. It will execute in that order. I have included this in my answer.

Comment: Actually problem is with my test.php file, if i put demo hello world  code in my test.php file its execute but when i put my Real code in test.php it shows error. Thanks.

Comment: Then the whole question changes, right? May be you can post a separate question for that.